Find Invalid Chars in a Column
I am moving data from one system to another.  The new system has a requirement that one of the columns can "ONLY have letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores".  I need to find a way to see all the rows for that column where chars other than those exist.
I started by doing something like this: MyCol NOT LIKE '%[a-z0-9]%'
But that does not work because many of the rows have those values, they just have other things (parens, slashes and spaces for example).
I need a way to say return any rows that have values that are not in [a-z0-9].  (Which is not the same as what I have above.)
Is there a way to do this in SQL Server's LIKE statement?

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156542/where-clause-with-pattern-matching-to-find-rows-with-any-characters-not-in-a-lis

LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]%'. watch out for weird collations where a-z doesn't come in that order though (i'm looking at you slovakia)

@siggermannen Ž is the last letter of most alphabets that contain it (like Czech), but exceptions include Estonian, Karelian, Veps, and Turkmen.

@Vaccano Is this for a lab system?

The Official Documentation is pretty good.

@BartMcEndree yeah but i think i or some other "normal" letter doesn't match [a-z] properly in czech or slovak

Query that finds only letters, number, underscores, and hyphens. To be safe you should escape the underscore and hyphen. The minus and hyphen sign are the same thing.
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyCol LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]%' ESCAPE '\'

research:
How do I escape multiple characters in an sql like string?
SQL Server Escape an Underscore
SQL Server how to escape plus and minus sign?
